Compilation and return values of infinite loops with try-catch blocks
I encountered this problem when experimenting with file I/O. This method compiles:
public static int testMethod1() {
        try {
            while (true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
        
    }

While these two do not:
public static int testMethod2() {
        try {
            while (true) { break; }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
        
    }

public static int testMethod3() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (false) {
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
        
    }

I cannot wrap my head around this. The first method is logically equivalent to the third. What is the compiler doing exactly?

What does the compiler say when it refuses to compile? And which Java version do you use?

This method must return a result of type int in both cases, and I'm on Java 17

By the way, you can make your examples minimal by removing the try/catch blocks, which are irrelevant and you'll still get the same compilation errors in the same methods. (And also remove the [tag:exception] tag.)

The compiler does not try to reason about the conditions under which the loop can break. It only notes that there is such a condition, whatever that may be. The reason why it does not try to reason about it is that you are skating dangerously close to the Halting Problem (q.v.), and Professors Church and Turing are frowning upon you.

I would add, the compiler could be made slightly smarter, to ignore any code that is conditional on a compile-time constant of false, but if they do that, someone will come up with a slightly more complicated example, and then another, and another. And why should we go down that road when no production code is ever going to look like this.


The first method is logically equivalent to the third

It is not. The if(false) does make a difference. The compiler does not evaluate this at compile time, thus it is possible for the code to reach the break, in which case you don't return anything (just like in the second snippet), which is the actual compilation error.
For more infomation regarding if(false), take a look at the JLS, which states all the way at the bottom:

The rationale for this differing treatment is to allow programmers to define "flag variables" such as:
static final boolean DEBUG = false;
and then write code such as:
if (DEBUG) { x=3; }


Thank you. Is this the explanation for your answer? Edit: Did not see your edit where you posted the same link :D
